# How to split up a column without using explode?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How would you split up a dataset containing

```
movie title     | movie genres 
Toy Story       | Animation|Children|Comedy
```

into

```
movie title | movie genres
Toy Story   | Animation
Toy Story   | Children
Toy Story   | Comedy
```

Without using the explode method as it is now depreciated

Comment: Look into `String.split()` that uses a reg ex delimiter as a param.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: have used `moviesDF.flatMap(row -> Arrays.asList(row.getString(2).split("\\|")).iterator(), Encoders.STRING());` so far but that only returns the genres split up and doesnt keep the title

Comment: [`explode` __function__](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is not deprecated..

Comment: according to this it is http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Comment: @elibretto you're confusing `org.apache.sql.functions.explode`, which is not deprecated, with `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<T>.explode` which is deprecated.

Comment: how could this function be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's "deprecated" in the sense that you can no longer call def explode on a dataset/dataframe. But the documentation also says that "you can explode columns either using functions.explode() or flatMap()"

Here's a Scala example that I was able to quickly test in scala REPL, but I'm sure this strategy works in Java:

```
import spark.implicits._

case class movie(title: String, genre: String)
val m1 = new movie("Toy Story", "Animation|Children|Comedy")

val df = Seq(m1).toDF()

df.show(5, false)
+---------+-------------------------+
|title    |granular_genre           |
+---------+-------------------------+
|Toy Story|Animation|Children|Comedy|
+---------+-------------------------+

val df2 = val df2 = df.select('title, explode(split('genre,"""\|""")).as("granular_genre")) 

df2.show(5, false)
+---------+--------------+
|title    |granular_genre|
+---------+--------------+
|Toy Story|Animation     |
|Toy Story|Children      |
|Toy Story|Comedy        |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: How would the explode line be converted into java?

Comment: You already know where to look up the API! Should be  `df.select(explode(split('genre, ..)).as..`